# How to fix "Unable to find a suitable output format for '/'" error in ffmpeg running with PHP

Tags: php, linux, cmd, ffmpeg, exec

I want to compress video on the server after the upload.
I installed correctly ffmpeg and when i run from the command line

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

it works!

But if i run the same command from PHP with exec,

```
class VideoCompress {
    function compress($path, $name){
        if (`which ffmpeg`) {
            exec("cd \"$path\";ffmpeg -i \"$name\" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 \"bk_$name\" / 2>&1", $o);
            print_r8($o);
        }
    }
}
```

it fails and return this error

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; ffmpeg version N-48518-g27c94c57dc-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] =&gt;   built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
    [2] =&gt;   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
    [3] =&gt;   libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
    [4] =&gt;   libavcodec     58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
    [5] =&gt;   libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
    [6] =&gt;   libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
    [7] =&gt;   libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
    [8] =&gt;   libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
    [9] =&gt;   libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
    [10] =&gt;   libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
    [11] =&gt; Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'WebHD_720p.mp4':
    [12] =&gt;   Metadata:
    [13] =&gt;     major_brand     : isom
    [14] =&gt;     minor_version   : 512
    [15] =&gt;     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    [16] =&gt;     encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    [17] =&gt;   Duration: 00:03:23.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1890 kb/s
    [18] =&gt;     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 9:10 DAR 8:5], 1754 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    [19] =&gt;     Metadata:
    [20] =&gt;       handler_name    : VideoHandler
    [21] =&gt;     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    [22] =&gt;     Metadata:
    [23] =&gt;       handler_name    : SoundHandler
    [24] =&gt; [NULL @ 0x59fb100] Unable to find a suitable output format for '/'
    [25] =&gt; /: Invalid argument
)
```

Any idea on how can i fix it?

Comment: *＋1* for asking a ffmpeg question that has to do with programming and development (and not just how to run a command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those commands aren't the same, the second one has a "/" instead of output.mp4

To help debugging do something like

```
if (`which ffmpeg`) {
    $command = "cd \"$path\";ffmpeg -i \"$name\" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 \"bk_$name\" 2>&1";
    print_r($command);
    exec($command, $o);   
}
```

Comment: yes, becouse the name of the file could have a space. 
I also tried to remove the quotes, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: if it's in quotes (which it is) then white space won't matter. Don't remove the quotes, remove the / so it looks like `-strict -2 \"bk_$name\" 2>&1"`

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. Now this problem is resolved, but the script return another error.
`[30] =&gt; Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
    [31] =&gt; [aac @ 0x72f3d80] Qavg: 65536.000
    [32] =&gt; [aac @ 0x72f3d80] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    [33] =&gt; Conversion failed!`

Comment: what is the value of $o?

Comment: Is to long to post here. follow the link to see the output error. https://www.codepile.net/pile/pzRdb0lb

Comment: using my code above, what is the value of $command?

Comment: `cd "/home/user/video";ffmpeg -i "WebHD_720p.mp4" -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 "bk_WebHD_720p.mp4" 2>&1`

Comment: Check that you can run the command above, from the same directory as php, and as the same user as php. Also check the output file doesn't exist. Either you can't open the output file, which is a permissions issue. Or your ffmpeg command doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem are the server resources. 
I'm using a test server with very low computing power. The error is shown immediately after the log "using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2".
I tried it on another more powerful server and everything worked. It is not a permission issue, the php user can write in this folder. However you answered my question, so now I approve it. Thank you very much, you have been very helpful.